# WordCloud of transaction activities in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am trying to generate a wordcloud from some transaction activities in order to show where people spend the most money. The transaction activities look like the following:

```
Description       Amount
Albertson         20
Albertson         30
Albertson         35
CVS               10
CVS               40
Walmart           15
Walmart           44
...
```

I can generate wordcloud easily by Description's frequency. But how can I get wordcloud which sorted by sum(amount) of each category? Thanks!

BTW here is my code

```
require(tm)
require(wordcloud)
require(RColorBrewer)

data_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(data))

data_corpus <- tm_map(data_corpus, content_transformer(tolower), mc.cores=1)
data_corpus <- tm_map(data_corpus, removePunctuation, mc.cores=1)
data_corpus <- tm_map(data_corpus, function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords()), mc.cores=1)
data_corpus <- tm_map(data_corpus, removeNumbers, mc.cores=1)

pal2 <- brewer.pal(8,"Dark2")
png("25-34.png", width=1280,height=800)
wordcloud(data_corpus, scale=c(6,.2),min.freq=50,max.words=Inf, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=.15, colors=pal2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: `frequency*amount` or just `sum(amount)` for each description? Show the code you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, I want to sort by sum(amount) for each category in descriptions. e.g. CVS is 50. And I just added my code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded your mini table into a dataframe called data. Then ran the following code:

```
require(wordcloud)
require(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)
# group by Description and sum the Amounts
data <- data %>% group_by(Description) %>% summarise(Amount = sum(Amount))

pal2 <- brewer.pal(8,"Dark2")
wordcloud(data$Description, freq = data$Amount, scale=c(6,.2),min.freq=50,max.words=Inf, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=.15, colors=pal2)
```

No need for the tm package. Just specify your description in the words section and the Amount in the frequency section.